# Additional drivers: "You are not authorized to perform this action"

Tags: drivers, sudo

Anytime I do anything requiring root privileges I need to enter my password and it works. With only one exception: running "Additional drivers", which simply complains "You are not authorized to perform this action".

I suppose that starting it with `sudo` should help, but how do I find out what's the real name of the "Additional drivers" application?

Or what else could I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called jockey, so just do `gksudo jockey` and that should work

Comment: Somehow it didn't work (it asked me for the password and then simply terminated; I'm afraid that my system is quite broken). But finding out `sudo jockey-kde` was easy and installed something.

Answer (score 4):

I found `gksudo jockey-gtk` brought it up (after asking for my password), I didn't have a `jockey` binary, my system just has the `jockey-gtk`.